# support for google xmp meta data with <a-sky>

Tags: aframe

With the 0.3.2 aframe, the `<a-sky>` doesn't seem to recognize google xmp metadata stored in photos.

If I use `<a-sky>` to display a partial pano, I will have to parse the metadata myself. Any suggestions on an easy and right way to do that ?

Comment: Is there anything `<a-sky>` should be doing with that xmp metadata? If you use `<a-assets/>` to load the image, there is a literal `<img>` tag added to the DOM, so you're free to do anything with that. I'm not familiar with parsing xmp metadata but perhaps something like this? https://github.com/cigalsace/metadata-js

Comment: I was hoping aframe could parse those metadata and set the atributes (theta-length, phi-length, ...) automatically. But aframe doesn't do that now. So I'm looking for a proper way to do that, like writing a component myself or whatever.@DonMcCurdy

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure those things are in the metadata? I think theta and phi lengths are THREE.js options for clipping the sphere, not anything to do with the equirectangular image itself, which is going to be 360º regardless.

Comment: This page gives some detail. https://developers.google.com/streetview/spherical-metadata. Many camera apps and 360 cameras include this in saved photos.@DonMcCurdy